# How many positive integers up to 100 can be written as a sum of 4 or more consecutive integers?

Tags: number-theory

I was trying to solve the question: how many positive integers $n \leq 100$ can be written as the sum of 4 or more consecutive integers.

Here was my approach:

Let $m$ represent the number of consecutive integers considered, and let $k$ be the starting integer.

For $m=4$:
$$ n = (k) + (k + 1) + (k + 2) + (k + 3) = 4k+6$$

So the inequality becomes:
$$4k+6 \leq 100$$
$$k \leq 23$$
So there are 23 solutions for $m=4$.

For $m=5$, using a similar approach there are 18 solutions.

In a similar vein, this can be done until $m=13$, when there is only 1 solution.
| $m$ | Number of solutions |
| --- | -------------------- |
| 4   | 23                   |
| 5   | 18                   |
| 6   | 14                   |
| 7   | 11                   |
| 8   | 9                    |
| 9   | 7                    |
| 10  | 5                    |
| 11  | 4                    |
| 12  | 2                    |
| 13  | 1                    |
In total, there are 94 solutions. However, there is double counting involved. This means that the real solution must be less than 94. So my question is how many positive integers are there less than 100 that cannot be written as a sum of 4 or more consecutive integers?

Comment: $k$ can be written as the sum of at least 4 consecutive integers when $2k = xy$ where $x,y$ have different parities and $x\ge y\ge 4$.

Comment: Instead of counting 23+18+... , may be count how many integers can NOT be written as sum of 4 or more consecutive integers. All integers <10 , then 11, 12, 13, 16, 17, 19  etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it is crucial to point out in the question, that we are interested in writing as the sum of $4$ or more consecutive **positive** integers. Otherwise, almost any positive integer $n$ number will do fine: $$n=(-n+1)+…+(-1)+0+1+…+(n-1)+n.$$

Let the number $n$ be equal to the sum of $m$ consecutive positive integers, where $m\ge4$: $$n=k+(k+1)+…+(k+m-1).$$

This is a sum of arithmetic progression, so $$n=\frac{m(k+k+m-1)}2= \frac{m(m+2k-1)}2.$$

Hence $n$ is good if and only if $2n$ can be represented as the product of two positive integers of different parity, the smaller of which is at least $4$. (Note, this agrees with @DS’s comment to the post.)

So, what numbers in $\{1,2,…,100\}$ are bad? Obviously all numbers from $1$ to $9$, they are too small, the minimal sum of $m$ consecutive positive integers is equal to $1+2+3+4=10$. It gives $\color{red}9$ bad numbers.

All the $2$-digit prime numbers are bad too. Since $2n$ can only be the product of $2$ and $n$, or $1$ and $2n$. Either way, one of the factors is less than $4$. This gives $\color{red}{21}$ bad numbers.

All the powers of $2$ are bad, since $2n$ is also a power of $2$. So it can’t be represented as the product of two numbers of different parity, except the case $1\cdot (2n)$, but $1<4$. This gives $\color{red}3$ bad numbers: $16,32,64$.

All tripled powers of $2$ are bad, too. Basically for the same reason: $3<4$. This gives $\color{red}4$ more bad numbers: $12,24,48,96$.

Any other number is good. Let’s take $n$ which doesn’t fall under any category mentioned before. Let $p$ be its greatest prime divisor (it’s not equal to $2$ or $n$). If $p>3$ then $2n$ can be represented as $$p\times\frac{2n}{p}.$$ Both factors are of different parity, and both are at least $4$. Inequality $\frac{2n}{p}\ge4$ follows from $n\ge 2p$, which is obviously true.

If $p=3$ then $n=2^a\cdot3^b$ for some non-negative $a$ and $b$. In fact, $b\ge2$ since $n$ is not a tripled power of $2$. If $b>2$ then $$2n= 2^{a+1}\cdot3^b = \left(2^{a+1}\cdot3\right) \times \left(3^{b-1}\right).$$ Both factors here are at least $4$. If $b=2$ then $a\ge 1$ since $n>9$. Then the following representation works:

$$2n= 2^{a+1}\times 3^2.$$ Both factors are at least $4$.

Thus, the answer to the question is $$100-\color{red}9 - \color{red}{21}- \color{red}3-\color{red}4=63.$$